# How to Save a record With out ValidationRule Fields on VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I created a VF page With some inputfield components these fields don't have any validation rules but when i am trying to save the records after entering the details in it. I am getting an error MSG as

```
Insert failed. The first exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You must review the preferences section before you can save this record.
```

There are some validation rules on other fields in the same object. According to my requirement I don't want validation fields on my VF page now.

```
    <apex:page controller="controllerclass">
        <style>
        .headerRow th{
            display:none;
        }
        </style>
          <apex:stylesheet value="/sCSS/21.0/sprites/1297816277000/Theme3/default/gc/versioning.css" />
              <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="opportunities2" id="theTabPanel"  >
                  <apex:tab label="tab1" id="Tabone" style="font-weight:bold;width:200px;">
                      <apex:pageblock title="New Lead">
                          <apex:pageblocksection >
                              <apex:form >
                              <apex:commandLink action="{!records}" immediate="true">
                                  <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Logo_Medium}" height="100" width="100" />
                              </apex:commandlink>
                              <br/>
                              <apex:commandLink action="{!action}" immediate="true">
                                  <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Logo_Transparent}" height="50" width="200" />
                              </apex:commandlink>
                               </apex:form>
                          </apex:pageblocksection>
                      </apex:pageblock>
                  </apex:tab>
                  <apex:tab label="tab2" id="TabTWO" style="font-weight:bold;width:200px;" name="opportunities2">
                      <apex:form >
                          <apex:pageblock title="Opportunities" mode="edit" >
                              <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                                  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!dosave}" style="Margin-left:250px" immediate="true"/>
                              </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                              <apex:pageblocksection >
                                  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Opportunities}" var="Opportunity" > 
                                      <apex:column headerValue="RecordTypeId" value="{!Opportunity.RecordTypeId}" />
                                      <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!Opportunity.name}" />
                                      <apex:column headerValue="StageName" value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>
                                      <apex:column headerValue="CloseDate" value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
                                      <apex:column headerValue="Sales Representative" value="{!Opportunity.Sales_Rep__c}"/>
                                      <apex:column headerValue="Date Of Appointment" value="{!Opportunity.Date_of_Appointment__c}"/>
                                  </apex:pageBlockTable>
                              </apex:pageblocksection>
                              <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2" >
                                  <apex:inputField label="Start" value="{!event.StartDateTime}" />
                                      <apex:selectList label="Sales Consultant" size="1" value="{!Consultantname}" >
                                          <apex:selectOptions value="{!ActiveSalesConsultant}" ></apex:selectOptions>
                                      </apex:selectList>
                                  <apex:inputField label="deal with" value="{!lead.LastName}" />&nbsp;
                                  <apex:inputField label="Duration" value="{!event.DurationInMinutes}"/>&nbsp;
                              </apex:pageBlockSection>
                              <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Information" columns="2">
                                  <apex:inputField value="{!ObjOpportunity.name}"/>
                                  <apex:inputField value="{!ObjOpportunity.StageName}"/>
                                  <apex:inputField value="{!ObjOpportunity.AccountId}"/>
                                  <apex:inputField value="{!ObjOpportunity.CloseDate}"/>
                              </apex:pageBlockSection>
                      </apex:pageblock> 
                      </apex:form> 
</apex:tabPanel>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: How about just search for the error text that you encounter and check which validation rule it matches up to. you can then tackle the problem at the source.

Comment: I see input for LastName, but not for Company. Are you providing that in the controller? Company is a required field unless Person Accounts are enbled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the property immediate="true" to your command button.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" immediate="true" action="{!save}"/>
```

Edited: Refer the link [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)

Comment: Thanks Guys for quick Reply I placed Immediate attribute next in commandButton but still I'm getting same error msg                               System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You must review the  preferences section before you can save this record: []
Error is in expression '{!dosave}' in component <apex:page> in page Opportunity

Comment: Which object record you are trying to insert ?

Comment: Standard object "lead"

Comment: Are you doing something using standardcontroller = "Opportunity"? Can u remove that and change extension to controller and try the same

Comment: Im pulling some Custom fields from lead object to vf page when trying to save the page showing me with a error msg

Comment: No Im Using Controller In My page ill post the page

Comment: Standard Validation you cant avoid with immediate=true but custom you can certainly

Comment: yup.. that will help..

Comment: @MohithKumar : rakesh s talking about custom validation oly..

Comment: Ya from the exception i see its custom validation .@rakesh Please put your code that we can debug .

Comment: here is the code now

Comment: Is the error from validation rule or trigger.. Check if the error is from trigger.. Coz immediate=true will only work on validation rules

Comment: error is from validation rule

Comment: Rakesh, am not sure if you have pasted the whole page code.. I can see that 2nd <apex:tab> tag is not closed properly..

Comment: i didnt paste that particular line but it exist in my code

Comment: Using immediate=true doesn't just avoid validation rules, it also discards any user input since the last postback.

Answer (score 11):

You can't turn off validation rules from a Visualforce page, as per the order of execution from the apex docs:

> On the server, Salesforce:
>
> .1. Loads the original record from the database or initializes the record for an upsert statement.
>   .2. Loads the new record field values from the request and overwrites the old values.
>   If the request came from a standard UI edit page, Salesforce runs system validation to check the record for:
>
> • Compliance with layout-specific rules
>
> • Required values at the layout level and field-definition level
>
> • Valid field formats
>
> • Maximum field length
>   ￼
>    Salesforce doesn't perform system validation in this step when the request comes from other  sources, such as an Apex application or a SOAP API call.
>
> .3. Executes all before triggers.
>
> .4. Runs most system validation steps again, such as verifying that all required fields have a non-null value, **and runs any user-defined validation rules**. The only system validation that Salesforce doesn't run a second time (when the request comes from a standard UI edit page) is the enforcement of layout-specific rules.

Using the immediate=true attribute on a component that submits the page (commandbutton, commandlink, actionfunction) does skip validation, but this is because the user input is discarded, as detailed in a response in this thread from one of the Salesforce product managers:

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/If-immediate-quot-true-quot-rerender-does-not-appear-to-work/td-p/77657

I've worked around this in the past using a hidden field on the record that is only set via Apex, which indicates to the validation rule that it should allow the record through regardless.  I wrote it up a while back in the following blog post:

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/bypass-validation-rules-from-apex.html