# Processing User Input Without Validation

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

*This seems to be a popular issue because there are related [questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/why-is-my-apex-throwing-this-error-on-my-visualforce-page) [all](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8574/problem-in-commandbutton-with-immediate-true) [over](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5219/how-to-save-a-record-with-out-validationrule-fields-on-vf-page) [the](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/inputtext-null-when-commandbutton-immediate-true/td-p/503873) [place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942372/inputfield-databinding-issue-with-visualforce). Rather than asking about this as buggy behavior, I'm trying to figure out best practices for my use-case.*

I have a common use case in Visualforce where I want to do some intermediate processing of user input on the server during the process of filling out a longer form, before trying to execute any save actions.  For this to work, I have the following requirements:

1. User input must be transmitted from the Visualforce page to the controller, so that I can execute logic against it.
2. Validation rules should not be enforced, because the user input isn't completed yet, and would be known to fail.

**I can't figure out any way to do this with standard `commandXXX` and `actionXXX` components:**

1. If I set `immediate=false` on the components, then VF tries to enforce validation rules.  My actionFunction never fires, because VF flags things like missing required fields.
2. If I set `immediate=true` on the components, then VF discards my user's input, and I can't do anything with it.
3. Using an `actionRegion` has the same problem - I can only get my actionFunction to execute by excluding fields that I want to consider in my logic.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Are you setting `required="true"` for all required fields?

Comment: Yes, I'm setting `required=true` for the fields which are required, either always or for completion of this (entire) page.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. I ended up with the following workaround.

- Do validation in controller with some apex
- Not using `required="true"` for required fields on the VF page but just ["simulate" it as required](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5462/required-field-mark-red-vertical-bar-not-coming/5466#5466)
- Use of `rerender="errorBlock"` in the command button or link to show the possible validation messages to the user after execution
- Use <kbd>Validate</kbd> <kbd>Save</kbd> buttons combination and enable the save button only if validation not fails
- Not use of `immediate="true"` at all

Here is some example. A simle VF page where user can input some information about object and save it. Before the save button will be activated the user needs to validate the form:

The page looks like this. The save button is disabled by default.

[image]

If user fills out only one field and click Validate button he will get an error message.

[image]

Only if both fields are filled out correctly the save button is active:

[image]

Here is the page code:

```
<apex:page controller="test1">

<apex:form>

    <apex:pageBlock id="theBlock">
        <apex:pageMessages/>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton reRender="theBlock" value="Validate" action="{!doValidation}"/>
            <apex:commandButton reRender="theBlock" value="Save" action="{!save}" disabled="{!isError}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Name"/>
                <apex:outputPanel>
                    <div class="requiredInput">
                        <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!t1Test.Name}"/>
                    </div>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="My Number"/>
                <apex:outputPanel>
                    <div class="requiredInput">
                        <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!t1Test.MyNumber__c}"/>
                    </div>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

And controller:

```
public with sharing class test1 {

    public Boolean isError { get; set; }
    public test1__c t1Test { get; set; }

    public test1(){
        t1Test = new test1__c();
        isError = true;
    }

    public PageReference doValidation()
    {
        String error = 'Please fill out following fields: ';
        isError = false;

        if(String.isBlank(t1Test.Name)){
            error += ' Name ';
            isError = true;
        }
        if(t1Test.MyNumber__c == null){
            error += ' MyNumber ';
            isError = true;
        }

        if(isError){
            ApexPages.Message alertMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, error);
            ApexPages.addMessage(alertMessage);            
        }

        return null;

    }

    public PageReference save(){
        try{    
            insert t1Test;
            System.debug('#### redirecting');
            Pagereference p = new PageReference('/' + t1Test.id);
            return p;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.Message alertMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(alertMessage);    
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```